# Spring batch - easiest way to get number of total records in CSV?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application that reads in CSV. What is the easiest way to get the number of records in the csv? I am a `FlatFileItemReader<T>` and I tried placing a counter in the `process()` method that we override for the `Processor`, that I thought would increment for every row in the csv but I was getting very odd integer numbers. I can't do it in my Writer() implementation class because I do data validation in my processor class so if there are exceptions, the record size will be smaller and it won't reflect the real number of records originally.

I just need to know if someone loads in a file with 300,000 but only 250,000 get written to database, I want to know the real number of records in the original csv.

Comment: The `FlatFileItemReader` already counts all the records read, you can get it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just need to know if someone loads in a file with 300,000 but only 250,000 get written to database, I want to know the real number of records in the original csv.

You can do that verification in a `StepExecutionListener#afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)`. This method gives you a reference to the step execution which allows you to get all counters like `read.count`, `write.count`, etc to implement your logic.

Comment: How does this compare to using the JobExplorer and getting stepExecution information from there? Also, where would it be best to "inject" the job explorer? I just want to check that, after a # of jobs are run, the data read, matches the data written etc... and that the exit code was "COMPLETED" and not some other failure....

Comment: The `JobExplorer` is typically used outside jobs, to explore the job repository after the fact. What I understood from your requirement is that you want to do that check **from within** the job, in a separate step or with a step/job listener.