# Spring Batch - Step Execution Context and AfterWrite method behaves unexpectedly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I use spring boot 3 with spring batch and my app runs on a k8s node on 4 pods. I use postgresql as job repository. My spring batch job consist of one step, which has a reader, a procesor anda  writer. I have a step listener, which goal is to count the number of read/processed/written objects from file. It may happen that batch jobs can run async on one node. It looks as follows:

```
static class StepListener {

    static final String OBJECT_COUNT = "OBJECT_COUNT";
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @AfterWrite
    private void incrementObjectCount(Chunk<? extends ExampleObjextt> objectss) {
        ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        int count = objects.size();
        if (executionContext.containsKey(OBJECT_COUNT)) {
            count += executionContext.getInt(OBJECT_COUNT);
        }
        executionContext.put(OBJECT_COUNT, count);
    } 
}
```

**This is an inner static class.** Which is then used as a listener in StepBuilder:

```
return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
            .<Object, Object>chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .listener(new StepListener())
            .build();
```

This code is executed after each chunk commit is done. After a job completion I should receive the number of read/written objects from a file. BTW. After I wrote it, I discovered that the number of read/written objects can be obtained from StepExecutionContext (methods getReadCount and getWriteCount). It's explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68206428/16798827

ReadCount and WriteCount are also stored in JobRepository in table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION in columns: read_count and write_count.

Recently I've discovered that the above logic does not work  sometimes as expected. I processed a file with 110 objects in my clustered application (with 4 nodes. In the logs I see that this file was picked up by one node and a job for it was created. It might also be that while this job was running, other job of the same kind was running also and other file was read) and the above logic saved in the end in step exec contec **OBJECT_COUNT = 230**. While the read_count and write_count in the database table for that step execution are 110. I can't reproduce it locally and it works as expected in 99% other cases.

How it is possible that OBJECT_COUNT was so different in that case? Is it due to clustered environment? Maybe this is due the fact, that listener is static inner class?

Comment: Your setup is not clear, at least to me. How are you running jobs? Do you have a job per file? If you really want to get correct stats, each file should be processed in a separate job instance (ie the file should be a job parameter).

Comment: Yes, I have a job per file. Chunk size is set to 10 and the file can contain single or multiple objects (even couple thousands). I switched to the solution, where I pick up stats from step execution context and as far it works as expected, but it still bothers me, why the above setup worked correctly in 99% of cases. The above failure occured multiple times.

Comment: I can't see why this happens from what you shared.

Comment: Me neither. As said before, your solution with usage of step execution context works perfectly.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you solved your issue by using the step execution context.